# forloop is looping but only the same string

Tags: powershell, for-loop, split, output

i'm trying to get the Installation ID for a few windows 7 units. 
this is what i have. iv'e tried moving the brackets and that helps or makes it worse depending on where i move it.

i have a list of ip addresses and i want it to output it with the ID and IP and it does that but it just repeats the first ip address. i'm assuming its just a formatting issue but thought id ask for help.

tried moving the array around, had to fiddle with the split command to get the output how i want it. now i just need to go ip by ip address and output like shown.

```bsh
# Read all the computers from the file
$computers = Get-Content "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\DavidsScripts\Test\input.txt"

# Perform an operation for each row in the file
$result = @(
  foreach ($strComputer in $computers) {
    cscript C:\Windows\System32\slmgr.vbs $strComputer username password /dti
  }
)

$result.split(":")[3, 4, 6] | Out-File -FilePath .\output.txt -Append
```

no errors just not going ip by ip address

changed username and password for obvious security reasons

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$result` contains an *array* of strings.

While `$result.split(":")` does apply splitting to the each element (courtesy of [*member-access enumeration*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44620191/45375)), it simply *concatenates* the resulting token arrays, returning a *single, flat* array.

Therefore, applying indexing to that flat array - `[3,4,6]` - returns only 3 elements *in total*, across all elements, which is not your intent.

Instead, **you must iterate over the elements of `$result` and split and slice *each element***:

```sh
$(
  foreach ($line in $result) {
    $line.Split(':')[3, 4, 6]
  }
) | Out-File -LiteralPath .\output.txt
```